# What are the requirements to charge a Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a 2017 13 inch MacBook Air, and I also have a big power bank. I am wondering, if it would be possible to charge my MacBook Air using that power bank. The power bank only has an output of 5V/2.4A. I am also wondering, how would you be able to find out the requirements for any Macbook device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Apple publishes technical specifications for its products and are available at its website.

Have a look at: [MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP753?locale=en_US)

Under **Battery and Power**<sup>2</sup> it shows:

- 45W MagSafe 2 Power Adapter with cable management; MagSafe 2 power port

As your power bank only has an output of 5V/2.4A, which would be 12 watts, it's little more the 1/4 the output of the 45W MagSafe 2 Power Adapter that comes with the MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017). It will charge it, but it will be very slow compared to using the 45W MagSafe 2 Power Adapter that comes with the MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017).

**Personally, I'd use the 45W MagSafe 2 Power Adapter that comes with the MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017), not your power bank.**